# Disable rdoc and ri from gemspec / Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rdoc

I have a client gem which I will distribute business clients via rubygems. Gem client has cca. dozen gem dependencies and when it is being installed it takes a long time to install it due to generation of `rdoc` and `ri` for each gem.

Clients are business user and they have no use for rdoc/ri, I am looking for a way to disable that via `.gemspec` or `Gemfile`. I am familiar with a solution which utilizes system file `.gemrc` to disable rdoc / ri. But that is not acceptable solution since I want my installation to be simple as typing:

`gem install foo`

Comment: so save it into a bash script? `echo 'gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc' > ~/.gemrc`

Comment: @shime How to trigger bash script on `gem install foo`?

Comment: ah, sorry for misunderstanding. now I understand what's the problem. it seems weird to me, though. I would not like for gem to be able to change my gem installing preferences globally. why wouldn't you simply instruct them to use `gem install foo --no-ri --no-rdoc`? I don't think there are any pre-installation hooks available.

Comment: @shime That is one of the ways but I was hoping I will find a way to do it automatic but after research it seems there is no option for this. Hvala Šime :)

Comment: haha, sorry for not being of more help!

Comment: Why not create a simple gem that shells out and puts 'gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc' into ~/.gemrc? Or have the application that they're installing setup .gemrc?

Comment: I have some basic doubts, please correct me if I'm wrong. If your clients are business users, then its really not their business to dabble with terminal commands, `gem install`, then using it through `irb`, etc. That is just technical stuff. If someone is doing those, they are techies, and its not a big deal to ask them to do `gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc`. I think that while you're trying to sweeten things up for them, it doesn't make operational sense.

Comment: @RDX It is little different in sense that gem is executable, meaning it will create executable ruby script in `/bin`. Client will not use it trough irb, but trough designed CLI. (command line interface).

Comment: Thanks @Dolphin (and sorry if my doubt had sounded blunt/rude)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [post-install message](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Specification.html#attribute-i-post_install_message) to explain that they can make it install quicker by running what @shime suggested: `echo 'gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc' > ~/.gemrc`